# RHEL - Install Xfce, but make using it optional

Tags: rhel, xfce

As a Masters student, I wish to avail of the the [RHEL developer programme](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/faqs-no-cost-red-hat-enterprise-linux).

However, my system of choice is Fedora - I really like the lightweight Xfce desktop - it does everything a desktop should, but is quite lightweight.

So, I'd like to use RHEL with the Xfce desktop. Now, a search of terms like "`rhel install xfce`" gives **loads** of links on how to do this.

My problem is that they **all** (at least as far as I've found) tell you how to turn it on by default.

What I want is to be able to boot into the shell, bring up Xfce (**if I want to**), or not and then be able to shut it down again, **if I want to**.

I want to do some benchmarking of distributed databases and don't want any GUI running while doing the the tests themselves, but would like to be able to bring up the GUI for various tasks from time to time, and then turn it off for testing.

I would be grateful if anyone could explain to me how I go about doing this.

Comment: Do you want to boot into the text login prompt rather than the graphical login?

Comment: @jsbillings - boot into prompt, do stuff, start up Xfce, do more stuff, turn off Xfce, do something else. Shutdown. Basically, I want to be able to swap between running a GUI and not running a GUI! Thanks for your interest. Am installing RHEL 8,.4 on a machine as we speak!

Comment: I suggest changing the default target to”multi-user.target” and use `startx` to start your graphical session.

Comment: @jsbillings - OK, how do I set the default target to "multi-user.target"?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/working-with-systemd-targets_configuring-basic-system-settings

Comment: @jsbillings - thanks for that helpful input. I can't try things at the minute - I've just had mechanical problems (missing disk due to no holding screws) - I'm awaiting delivery of a new toolkit (old one was nicked...) and will tackle issue in the coming days. I'll report back then.